# Assigning text property randomly to textblockes in C# windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I assigned 50 text blocks with names `_1, _2,_3,....,_50` and I managed to store the name in an array using for loop. Like this:

```
string[] textname = new string[51];
for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
     textname[i] = "_" + i.ToString();
}
```

But I want to assign text property to the textblocks with name in the string array.
How this can be done?

Comment: Have you got an array of TextBlocks already?

Comment: Perhaps use the Tag property of the TextBlock to store your desired string?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to reference controls from the code. I'd suggest an alternative (MVVM) approach.

Since you're accesing your text blocks by index I suppose they're displayed in a list. This means you could create them in XAML as an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `Strings` property that you're binding to should be an `ObservableCollection` so that UI will be notified of any changes:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private string _path;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Strings.Add("Value " + i);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the page you need to set `ViewModel` as `DataContext`:

```
DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

You can modify values directly in the `Strings` collection:

```
viewModel.Strings[12] = "NewValue";
```

If for some reason you need to arrange your text blocks individually on the page you could do that as well and bind to the right index in the collection:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings[12]}" />
```

Thouhg in this case it would make more sense to have individual named properties instead of indexing them in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you only have an array of strings, what you need is an array (or List, which I think is easier to use) of `TextBlocks`.

```
List<TextBlock> list = new List<TextBlock>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++)
{
list.Add(new TextBlock() {Text = "something you want to put here", Tag = "_" + i});
}
```

Or if you really want to use an Array:

```
TextBlock[] arr= new TextBlock[51];
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i ++)
{
arr[i] = new TextBlock() {Text = "something you want to put here", Tag = "_" + i});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answers point out that perhaps your approach is not appropriate, I find that it should still be necessary to explain to you how to actually do what you want to accomplish. You need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535795.aspx) to access a property by name. Note that the example I give you is specific to **Windows Store Apps** as it is slightly different for other project types.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
var textbox = properties.Single(prop =>
    String.Equals(prop.Name, "_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .GetValue() as TextBox;

if (textbox != null)
{
    var originalValue = textbox.Text;

    textbox.Text = "new value";
}
```

---

Note that you can replace the **"_1"** with any string value of the property name to get the appropriate value. I also used the `Single(...)` LINQ method by making an assumption that you will always have a matching property name, your requirements might differ. I should also point out that while this is a solution, it's probably better to rethink your design so you don't have to use Reflection to access the properties.